# sbt fails with stackoverflow while maven works fine

Tags: maven, sbt

For the sake of testing, I created an empty project with only one file `build.sbt` which contains only one line:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.openprovenance.prov" % "prov-interop" % "0.7.2"
```

If I run `sbt update` it fails with stack overflow. The last lines look like this (you can imagine the repeated nested attempts to fetch dependencies):

```
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:731)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:748)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:731)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:748)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
[error] (*:update) java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 21, 2015 11:50:37 PM
```

I have the same dependency in a maven project, and there the dependency is downloaded without any problems. How can I solve this in sbt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the following dependency at very beginning of your `libraryDependencies`:

```
"org.antlr" % "antlr-runtime" % "3.4"
```

**Update:** better to use the antlr-runtime

**Update 2:** the given solution does not solve the problem completely, this problem is causes by a recursive dependency declared in the `prov-interop` dependency tree. To solve declare it like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
    "org.openprovenance.prov" % "prov-model" % "0.7.2",
    "org.openprovenance.prov" % "prov-interop" % "0.7.2" exclude("org.antlr", "stringtemplate"), // to resolve cyclic dependencies
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar exception for a different jar (one that I built myself and deployed to a private repository). Can you please explain what the issue here is, and why the addition of `antlr-runtime` solves it? Thanks

Comment: @tzach-zohar, The root of the issue was in a recursive dependency caused by `prov-interop`. Apparently using `prov-interop` in `maven` is fine but when used in `sbt` it causes a recursive dependency with different versions of `antlr-runtime`.  So at the end based on the dependency tree assessment, the best solution is to `exclude("org.antlr", "stringtemplate")`.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!